# .NET 2.0: Sending email to a distribution group

Tags: c#, email, .net-2.0

Good day,

We just converted our web application .NET 1.1 to .NET 2.0. We have a major problem sending emails.

We are using distribution group (eg:  WebDeveloppersGroup) to send emails to all the developpers in the company. These groups don't end with '@ something.com'. These groups are created in Lotus Notes, and we cannot access all the individual emails contained in these groups

In .NET 2.0 you cannot use email.To and are required to use:  email.To.Add("WebDeveloppersGroup");

This causes a System.Format with the following message:

The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.

Does anyone know how to send to an email group in 2.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can interact with Lotus Notes from .net and query it to get you the xyz@xyz.xyz addresses in the group. I'm not very familiar with it but you could start here:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/lotusnoteintegrator.aspx
- [IBM Lotus Notes and .NET](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-msnet/index.html?S_TACT=105AGX13&S_CMP=EDU)

Good luck!

Comment: It would be far less work to assign full internet addresses to the group(s).

Answer (score 2):

You can give the groups a full internet e-mail address. Ask your admin if you don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I have to assume here that if this was allowed *and* working in .Net 1.1 it was because either .Net or the OS were appending the domain onto the group name "WebDeveloppersGroup", which is probably "WebDeveloppersGroup@yourdomain.com".  The group may not be displayed that way in Lotus, but to receive external email at that address it must have been resolving before.  To test this I would just append you domain name onto the address and see if it works.